# How does using singleton patterns in Android impact memory usage?

Tags: android, singleton

I'm thinking about using singleton patterns for adapters and helpers in an Android app that I'm building, but I'm not too familiar with Java's garbage collecting and how static attributes (eg `static FooBar instance`) impact memory usage.

Will it have a big enough impact in Android apps that I should avoid using it?

Comment: It depends on your code. If you could potentially have multiple instances that do the same thing, a singleton will use less memory because it's not storing multiple instances of the same object.

Comment: There is a myth, invented because people do not understand the activity life cycle, that Android somehow "decides" to free up variables.  It does not.  It's garbage collector is like any other.  if you have one or more references to an object, it will not be collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "impact memory usage". An object isn't larger or smaller just because there is one instance of it enforced by a singleton pattern. In that sense there's no difference.

If it means you definitely have at most one copy of an object in memory instead of several, yes it could help.

Usually what people mean though, is, how long does the singleton live? does it stick around taking up memory when the app is in the background?

A `static` member is attached to an instance of its `Class` which is in turn attached to its `ClassLoader`. So the singleton lives as long as the `ClassLoader`. It turns out in Android that the app's `ClassLoader` goes away in `onDestroy`, not `onPause`, so a singleton implies you hold on to the memory even when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it depends.  The case where it could be bad is if the singleton is holding references to objects that could otherwise be garbage collected.  If there are a lot of references in the object, or references to large objects, you could be using memory you don't need.  You could work around it by using weak references, but then you have to have code to recreate the objects when needed if they get garbage collected.  You could not use the singleton pattern, which would allow things to get garbage collected (at least potentially), but at the expense of creating and throwing away objects.  The best solution depends on the details of the object and its usage.  One thing to always avoid is holding on to a reference to a UI object, such as a View.